# Convert nested struct to JSON

Tags: json, ruby

I find the answer for the reverse but not for the way nested struct to JSON

Suppose that I have this ruby structs

```
Attributes = Struct.new :name, :preferredLanguage, :telephoneNumber, :timeZone
User = Struct.new :email, :service, :preferredLanguage, :attributes
```

I create the struct for Attributes

```
attributes = Attributes.new "Pedro", "es", "5555555", "Madrid"
 # => #<struct Attributes name="Pedro", preferredLanguage="es", telephoneNumber="5555555", timeZone="Madrid"> 
attributes.to_h.to_json
 # => "{\"name\":\"Pedro\",\"preferredLanguage\":\"es\",\"telephoneNumber\":\"5555555\",\"timeZone\":\"Madrid\"}" 
Oj.dump attributes
 # => "{\"^u\":[\"Attributes\",\"Pedro\",\"es\",\"5555555\",\"Madrid\"]}" 
Oj.dump attributes, mode: :compat
 # => "\"#<struct Attributes name=\\\"Pedro\\\", preferredLanguage=\\\"es\\\", telephoneNumber=\\\"5555555\\\", timeZone=\\\"Madrid\\\">\""
```

So it works well, except when I use the gem `Oj`, that I cannot remove the name of the object and get the same as with the `to_h.to_json` methods

But the problem comes when I use a nested Struct like User

```
user = User.new "Pedro@email.com", "coolService", "es", attributes
 # => #<struct User email="Pedro@email.com", service="coolService", preferredLanguage="es", attributes=#<struct Attributes name="Pedro", preferredLanguage="es", telephoneNumber="5555555", timeZone="Madrid">> 
user.to_h.to_json
 # => "{\"email\":\"Pedro@email.com\",\"service\":\"coolService\",\"preferredLanguage\":\"es\",\"attributes\":\"#<struct Attributes name=\\\"Pedro\\\", preferredLanguage=\\\"es\\\", telephoneNumber=\\\"5555555\\\", timeZone=\\\"Madrid\\\">\"}" 
Oj.dump user, mode: :compat
 # => "\"#<struct User email=\\\"Pedro@email.com\\\", service=\\\"coolService\\\", preferredLanguage=\\\"es\\\", attributes=#<struct Attributes name=\\\"Pedro\\\", preferredLanguage=\\\"es\\\", telephoneNumber=\\\"5555555\\\", timeZone=\\\"Madrid\\\">>\""
```

With the `to_h.to_json` I get the string of the attributes object, And with the oj, this is not a valid JSON. and also I have another question, there is any GSON, jackson library from java that works the same way in ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to use ActiveSupport (Rails), you would get this out of the box. As you seem to be using barebones Ruby, just do it recursively:

```
hashify = lambda do |struct|
  as_hash = struct.to_h
  struct_keys = as_hash.select { |_, v| v.is_a? Struct }.map(&:first)
  struct_keys.each { |key| as_hash[key] = hashify.(as_hash[key]) }
  as_hash
end

hashify.(user).to_json
  # => "{\"email\":\"Pedro@email.com\",\"service\":\"coolService\",\"preferredLanguage\":\"es\",\"attributes\":{\"name\":\"Pedro\",\"preferredLanguage\":\"es\",\"telephoneNumber\":\"5555555\",\"timeZone\":\"Madrid\"}}"
```

As for GSON, there seems to be [a wrapper for Ruby](https://github.com/avsej/gson.rb), but I don't think it's that widely used. Rails' monkey patched behaviour is good enough for 99.99% of possible uses. It also lets you define your custom serializers if you want to change it.